# Return a different value:key pair

Tags: javascript

I need to return a different value:key based on a different value:key returned from a function

`return maxSize` correctly provides the array inside the object but now I need a different value based on that return. i.e. I returned the correct size with the maximum amount in the array and now I need the name title(string) from the same array set.

```
let maxSize = 0;
data.map(function(obj){
  if (obj.size > maxSize) maxSize = obj.size;
});
return maxSize
```

Comment: `now I need the name title(string)` ... what does this mean? there's no code that relates to this - why are you using `map` when you are not `map`ping values? *use `forEach` instead - it makes code easier to understand if you use the appropriate methods*

Comment: understood, while it still gives me the correct return based on my function, i need it to return an associated value:key pair in that array.